# Show current location in google map programmatically android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I can get current location manually but I want to get it programmatically in android app. I am using `LocationListener` and `LocationManager` but I am not getting current location on map. My code is given below, anybody can guide me how can I do that?

```
package com.example.nabia.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class FindNearbyMosque extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapView gMapView;
    GoogleMap gMap = null;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_nearby_mosque);

        LocationManager myManager;
        myManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


        gMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        gMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        gMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        gMap = map;
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        gMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude) , 14.0f) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by connecting `LocationServices`through `GoogleApiClient()` as you can see in below code.

```
public class FindNearbyMosque extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    double lat;
    double lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

            if (initMap()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_nearby_mosque);
        }
    }

    private boolean servicesOK() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to google play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return (true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            CameraUpdate center=
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc);
            CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc,14);
            mMap.moveCamera(center);
            mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```